# Not able to Delete Objects from Amazon S3 using java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to list Objects based on prefix folder and delete each object.

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("accesskey", "secretkey");
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = 
               new ListObjectsRequest("bucketname","folder",null,"/",1000);

s3client
      .listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
      .getObjectSummaries()
      .forEach(
          (file) -> {
            DeleteObjectRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest("bucketname", file.getKey());
            s3client.deleteObject(deleteRequest);
          });
```

But i am getting following Exception

**com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;**

```
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4187)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4134)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4128)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:839)
```

The keys I am using are valid. I can perform other operations like `getobject()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Question title looks wrong. You are able to list objects; but not delete objects. This looks to be permission problem.

User associated with the keys does not have permission to delete objects on that S3 bucket. Easiest way to check this would be to login as that user on AWS console ( if that user has aws console username/password); and try deleting the object manually.

Comment: No actually if i remove "delete" logic and trying am got the same error

Comment: you can see the log trace i have posted in question...     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:839)

Comment: getObject() and listObjects() are different permissions.. This user does not have listObjects() permission